# Dart - secret key generation method

Tags: dart, secret-key, ecdh, pointycastle

I am looking for a dart package in order to implement key exchange protocol (Elliptic-curve Diffie–Hellman) in a Flutter application.

- app generates a key pair during login and sends the public key to server (so a new key pair is generated for every login)
- server sends back its public key that it just generated
- app generates a secret key from its private key and server's public key
- app includes the hmac of all subsequent messages sent to the server

I took a look at pointycastle, which has supported Diffie–Hellman. But I don't find any method where to generate a secret key. This is what java does to generate:

```
 KeyAgreement a = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH", "SC");
 a.init(mProvisionerPrivaetKey);
 a.doPhase(publicKey, true);
```

Wonder if there's some clue you found to generate a secret key from its private key and server's public key in dart.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to generate a Java compatible shared secret from a local EC key pair and the server's public point using `pointycastle`. (Note that Java's `KeyAgreement` only uses the `x` co-ordinate of the point - `y` is unused. I'm not familiar with the `SC` provider, which may do things differently.)

```
Uint8List sharedSecret(AsymmetricKeyPair localPair, ECPoint remotePublicPoint) {
  var ss = remotePublicPoint * (localPair.privateKey as ECPrivateKey).d;
  return hex.decode(toHex(ss.x.toBigInteger()));
}
```

`toHex` is a utility that prints a `BigInt` to hex, making sure that there are an even number of hex digits.

```
String toHex(BigInt bi) {
  var hex = bi.toRadixString(16);
  return (hex.length & 1 == 0) ? hex : '0$hex';
}
```

`hex.decode` is from `package:convert` (notice - not `dart:convert`) so be sure to add it to `pubspec.yaml` and import it: `import 'package:convert/convert.dart';`

Finally, to parse the server's public point from hex in the form `aaaaaa,bbbbbb` use:

```
ECPoint parsePoint(String s) {
  var parts = s.split(',');
  return domainParams.curve.createPoint(
    BigInt.parse(parts[0], radix: 16),
    BigInt.parse(parts[1], radix: 16),
  );
}
```

where `domainParams` is your curve, for example:

```
var domainParams = ECCurve_secp256k1();
```

Comment: do you have any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151318/aes-encryption-in-flutter-not-working-properly